# iOS react-native-firebase - Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID after upgrade to RN 0.60?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

Before upgrading from react native 0.59 to 0.60, all was good.

Xcode 10.3 build error:

```
/bin/sh -c myApp.build/Script-6C5554832063F4750081EA9D.sh

error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

Again everything worked before upgrading firebase and react native.

I had a working /ios/GoogleService-Info.plist

In my project's Build Phases > Run Script

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"
```

File: package:json

```
"react": "^16.9.0",
"react-native": "^0.60.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
```

File: Podfile

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.3.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 6.3.0'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.13.2'
```

Before upgrading from react native 0.59 to 0.60, all was good.

Can anyone advise what else I can check?

Comment: I think we should ask the firebase team.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a compatibility issue. You might want to downgrade back to 0.59 and check if that resolves the issue. If it doesn't help, then there's an issue with the code that you might have changed while upgrading to 0.60.

Comment: Thank you.  I am committed to using AndroidX and 0.60 and cannot downgrade.  I will make a new 0.60 project, then add react-native-firebase and crashlytics.  If it works then I will try to find the difference between my two projects.

Comment: That should help too

Answer (score 0):

The [react-native-firebase docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios) are very good.  If it appears you are doing everything correctly, check this:

**Solved:**

1. Move the run script **"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"** to the end of the xcode target's, Build Phases.

[image]